# Optimization using scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to build an efficient frontier as in the Markowitz problem.
I have written the code below, but I get the error "ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar". I have tested 'fun' with some values, for example, I input to the console:

```
W = np.ones([n])/n     # start optimization with equal weights
cov_matrix = returns.cov() 
fun = 0.5*np.dot(np.dot(W, cov_matrix), W)    # variance of the portfolio
fun
```

The output is 0.00015337622774133828, which is a scalar.
I don't know what might be wrong. Any help is appreciated.

## Code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('path/Assets_3.xlsx') # in this workbook there is data for returns.
# The next lines clean unnecessary first column and first row.
ws = wb.active
df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
df1 = df.drop(0,axis=1)
df1 = df1.drop(0)
df1 = df1.astype(float)

rf = 0.05
r_bar = 0.05
returns = df1.copy()

def efficient_frontier(rf, r_bar, returns):   
    n = len(returns.transpose())
    W = np.ones([n])/n     # start optimization with equal weights
    exp_ret = returns.mean() 
    cov_matrix = returns.cov() 

    fun = 0.5*np.dot(np.dot(W, cov_matrix), W)    # variance of the portfolio

    cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda W: sum(W) - 1. },  
         {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda W: np.dot(exp_ret,W) - r_bar })

    bnds = [(0.,1.) for i in range(n)]    # weights between 0..1. 

    res = minimize(fun, W, (returns, cov_matrix, rf), 
                method='SLSQP', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)
    return res

x= efficient_frontier(rf,r_bar,returns)
x
```

## Some Data

```
           1         2         3   
1   0.060206  0.005781  0.001117    
2   0.006463 -0.007390  0.001133    
3  -0.003211 -0.015730  0.001167    
4   0.044227 -0.006250  0.001225    
5  -0.040571 -0.006910  0.001292    
6  -0.007900 -0.006160  0.001208    
7   0.068702  0.013836  0.001300    
8   0.039286  0.009854  0.001350    
9   0.012457 -0.007950  0.001358    
10 -0.013758  0.001021  0.001283    
11 -0.002616 -0.013600  0.001300    
12  0.059004 -0.006090  0.001442    
13  0.015566  0.002818  0.001308    
14 -0.036454  0.001395  0.001283    
15  0.058899  0.011072  0.001325    
16 -0.043086  0.017070  0.001308    
17  0.023156 -0.003350  0.001392    
18  0.063705  0.000301  0.001417    
19  0.017628 -0.001960  0.001508    
20 -0.014567 -0.006990  0.001525    
21 -0.007191 -0.013000  0.001425    
22 -0.000815  0.014773  0.001450    
23  0.046493 -0.001540  0.001542    
24  0.051832 -0.008580  0.001742    
25 -0.007151  0.001177  0.001633    
26 -0.018196 -0.008680  0.001642    
27 -0.013513 -0.008810  0.001675    
28 -0.026493 -0.010510  0.001825    
29 -0.003249 -0.014750  0.001800    
30  0.001222  0.022258  0.001758
```

Comment: `fun` doesn't seem to be a function.

Comment: It's supposed to be a function of the weights W and the covariance matrix cov_matrix.

Comment: Are you sure you are not returning an `np.array` with shape (1), intead of a `float`?

Comment: @MatteoRagni If i put instead fun = float(0.5*np.dot(np.dot(W, cov_matrix), W)), I get the same error.

Comment: Uh ma `fun` is not a callable object! Probably that is the issue....

Comment: @user2357112 how do I turn it into a function? I tried doing def fun(W,cov_matrix):
    fun = float(0.5*np.dot(np.dot(W, cov_matrix), W))    # variance of the portfolio
    return fun

Comment: @MatteoRagni what do you mean? (sorry, I am very new to python and programming in general)

Comment: Add a reproducible example using synthetic data or add your data.

Comment: Still not a reproducible example and it seems you are mixing some data-structures here: np-array, pandas-series/dataframes...

Comment: @sascha Sorry... I am learning Python and I am not from computer science. What can I do to make it better for you?

Comment: Add code that we can run as you do making the same observations. And no offense: but given your previous programming background, that's a bad first task!

Answer (score 3):

This code is a mess and while i can show you something which runs, that does not mean anything.

You will see convergence to your starting-point, whatever that means in your task! It's a strong indicator that something is still very wrong (might be the underlying theory)!

Some additional remarks:

- scipy's optimizers are build to work with numpy-arrays, not pandas Dataframes or Series objects!

  - the only things in your original question which hinted pandas-usage was a var-name `df` and  `returns.cov()` which does not exist for numpy-arrays!
- rf is never used anywhere!
- there are multiple things in optimize's args, which are not used!
- it does not feel like a problem one should use scipy's optimizers for! (but it's possible; here we are paying for numerical-differentiation for example)

  - [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/index.html) would probably a much much better approach (more clean, faster, more accurate) if interpret the problem correctly (did not analyze much)
  - but the same rules apply: some python-knowledge is needed!

Code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rf = 0.05
r_bar = 0.05
returns = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30, 3), columns=list('ABC'))  # PANDAS DF
cov_matrix = returns.cov().as_matrix()                               # use PANDAS one last time
                                                                     # but result = np.array!
returns = returns.as_matrix()                                        # From now on: np-only!

def fun(x, returns, cov_matrix, rf):
    return 0.5*np.dot(np.dot(x, cov_matrix), x)

def efficient_frontier(rf, r_bar, returns):
    n = len(returns.transpose())
    W = np.ones([n])/n     # start optimization with equal weights
    exp_ret = returns.mean()

    cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1. },         # let's use numpy here
         {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.dot(exp_ret, x) - r_bar })

    bnds = [(0.,1.) for i in range(n)]    # weights between 0..1.

    res = minimize(fun, W, (returns, cov_matrix, rf),
                method='SLSQP', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)
    return res

x= efficient_frontier(rf,r_bar,returns)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
A         B         C
A  0.813375 -0.001370  0.173901
B -0.001370  1.482756  0.380514
C  0.173901  0.380514  1.285936
fun: 0.2604530793556774
jac: array([ 0.32863522,  0.62063321,  0.61345008])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nfev: 35
nit: 7
njev: 3
status: 0
success: True
x: array([ 0.33333333,  0.33333333,  0.33333333])
```

Comment: @MatteoRagni It's a question hard to work with. Especially until one recognizes that ```np_array.cov()``` does not exist.

Comment: Looking further into the results, I realized that in spite of outputting a result, the code does not optimize anything. Whatever W  I choose to input as initial weights will be the final result of the weights and 'fun' is exactly the objective function when inputting these values.

Comment: That's what i told in the first place. The second sentence of my answer is important and without a clear problem-statement (theory of the problem) there is not much to help.